# Horizontal gallery scroll stop selecting image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, gallery

I have this jQuery for a gallery in my website so when i click on a i mage i can swipe to right or left. Only problem is, when i release the click. It selects the image my mouse landed on.

Can i prevent this in anyway?

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var scroll = 0;


    $(function () {
        var clicked = false, clickX;

        $("#gallery").on({


            'mousemove': function(e) {
                clicked && updateScrollPos(e);

            },
            'mousedown': function(e) {
                clicked = true;
                clickX = e.pageX;
                scroll = $('#gallery').scrollLeft();
                e.preventDefault();

            },
            'mouseup': function() {
                clicked = false;
                $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');

            }

        });

        var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
            $('#gallery').scrollLeft(scroll + (clickX - e.pageX));
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

good example of my current code http://jsfiddle.net/qtfLjb3n/

after each image sits content what gets loaded after the click. ( so annoying if it clicks when you are just scrolling).